# Ошибка при установке Symfony: Cannot redeclare assetic_init()

Tags: php, symfony2, assetic

Я использую `Assetic` с `Symfony2`, однако когда я устанавливаю `Symfony` возникает ошибка:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare assetic_init() (previously declared in D:\site\gsc.local\vendor\kriswallsmith\assetic\src\functions.php:24) in D:\site\service.ru\vendor\kriswallsmith\assetic\src\functions.php on line 30
```

Использую `Apache` в `Windows 7`. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: На данном ресурсе говорят по-русски.

Comment: у вас почему-то грузятся две копии assetic. Вам необходимо понять, почему используется как gsc.local, так и service.ru.

Comment: Что значит фраза "когда я устанавливаю Symfony"? Сформулируйте вопрос более четко. Я до сих пор не понял, как Вы добились такой ситуации. Ответов может быть тысяча... это гадание на кофейной гуще.